# Have crash report, dsym file but not the ipa / xarchive: How to symbolicate the crash log?

Tags: ios, xcode, crash-reports

I have done a TestFlight build yesterday and switched from one Mac to another location.

Today I see, that there are crashes in the Crash Organizer but they are not symbolicated.

I have the dSym file from the build in TestFlight downloaded, I have the source code for that build (some fixes have been applied since yesterday, but having a class and line will still be very helpful) - but I do not have the actual build on the Mac in the office here.

How can I apply the symbols to the crashlog?

UPDATE: I tried calling `symbolicatecrash` directly, but it is not reachable in the path. I had to call it with the full path set

```
imac:Contents thst$ pwd
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents
imac:Contents thst$ ./SharedFrameworks/DTDeviceKitBase.framework/Versions/A/Resources/symbolicatecrash ...
```

Then it complained about `DEVELOPER_DIR` not set, so I set it to

```
export DEVELOPER_DIR=`xcode-select -p`
```

This made it start at least, but now I get errors like this:

```
xcodebuild: error: SDK "ipados" cannot be located.
xcrun: error: unable to find utility "otool", not a developer tool or in PATH
## Warning: can't find tool named 'otool' in the ipados SDK, falling back to searching the iOS SDK
xcodebuild: error: SDK "ipados" cannot be located.
xcrun: error: unable to find utility "atos", not a developer tool or in PATH
## Warning: can't find tool named 'atos' in the ipados SDK, falling back to searching the iOS SDK
xcodebuild: error: SDK "ipados" cannot be located.
xcrun: error: unable to find utility "lipo", not a developer tool or in PATH
## Warning: can't find tool named 'lipo' in the ipados SDK, falling back to searching the iOS SDK
xcodebuild: error: SDK "ipados" cannot be located.
xcrun: error: unable to find utility "size", not a developer tool or in PATH
## Warning: can't find tool named 'size' in the ipados SDK, falling back to searching the iOS SDK
## Warning: Unable to symbolicate from required binary: /Users/thst/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS DeviceSupport/8.4 (12H143)/Symbols/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreMotion.framework/CoreMotion
Incident Identifier: B2F71703-1CE2-4CDE-A6A8-3C51FDE9DBFF
Beta Identifier:     DD46FE78-8872-4DF1-BF83-58796766B994
Hardware Model:      iPad2,2
```

calling `otool` on the commandline works:

```
imac:Contents thst$ otool
Usage: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/otool [-arch arch_type] [-fahlLDtdorSTMRIHGvVcXmqQjCP] [-mcpu=arg] [--version] <object file> ...
    -f print the fat headers
    -a print the archive header
    ...
```

So it is on the path actually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the IAP file, just the crash file and the dsym file. Use the following command in the terminal:

```
./symbolicatecrash crashFile.crash dsymFile.dSYM > crashLog.txt
```

Comment: I have XCode7 installed but there is no such tool in the commandline, I found it deeply buried in the Xcode archive contents and found another SO topic on that issue, but I get all kind of errors about tools not on the path (size, atos, otool, lipo) which are definitely there.

Comment: This did not entirely solve my issue, but it seems that the crashlog is indeed symbolicated at the end, but there is simply no symbol of my code on the line of crash. I will open another question to actually understand the output better. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Did not follow this any further, waiting for the next incident to happen.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, ensure the Xcode application name as it is for DEVELOPER_DIR.
Eg: I had named my xcode app as xcode 7.2 in Applications. But I set

$DEVELOPER_DIR='/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer'; in symbolicatecrash.

Issue resolved once I set like below

$DEVELOPER_DIR='/Applications/Xcode 7.2.app/Contents/Developer';